# Convert a otpauth URI to a one-time-password

Tags: authentication, oauth, two-factor-authentication

So I was given a QR code for two-factor-authentication access to a well-known website (bitstamp.net).

When I scan the QR code, I get a raw otpauth URI:

```
otpauth://totp/000000@Bitstamp?secret=A23UCSQTHJADET2I
```

(The above userid is set to "000000" and the secret is jumbled...)

Now, when I type the following into the command line (Ubuntu 14.04, clock is up-to-date)

```
oathtool --totp --base32 A23UCSQTHJADET2I
```

I get a 6 digit number:

```
301025
```

This is the wrong number!!!

When I scan the exact same QR code into Google Authenticator (on an Android phone), it gives me a totally different number (the number provided by Google Authenticator works perfectly and allows me to login to bitstamp.net)

I'm totally stuck now ;( Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your server's time isn't synced properly.

Try installing a package called `ntp` and start it via `sudo /etc/init.d/ntp start`